# XCode: New Certificate not listed

Tags: xcode

Our deployment certificate is expiring. I've gone to Apple's site and created a new certificate, and downloaded this certificate to my keychain.

I'm trying to set up a new provisioning profile for this certificate, but when I go into the Organizer in XCode and refresh my certificate list, my new certificate isn't listed.

Is there a delay or something before a new certificate is available in the provisioning profiles? Or is there another way to get this new certificate to be listed in the provisioning profiles section?

I'm using the latest version of XCode (4.6, I believe).

Comment: Did you tried to **refresh** the information in the Organizer/Devices section of Xcode?

Comment: Yes, the new certificate is not listed in the Organizer when I refresh. (That's why I was wondering whether there was a delay between creating a certificate and having it appear in the organizer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out - I needed to create the provisioning profile on Apple's site.

What I wouldn't give for a set of instructions from Apple, like "Need to update your profile? Do this..."